# Pytest indirect parametrization using anyio

Tags: parameters, pytest, pytest-fixtures, python-anyio

Pytest offers a way to parametrize fixture just before running test function ([documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/example/parametrize.html#indirect-parametrization))

But I am trying to write async tests using [AnyIO](https://anyio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/testing.html#)

Below is my modified code from example

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def anyio_backend() -> str:
    return "asyncio"


@pytest.fixture
async def fixt(request):
    return request.param * 3


@pytest.mark.anyio
@pytest.mark.parametrize("fixt", ["a", "b"], indirect=True)
async def test_indirect(fixt):
    assert len(fixt) == 3
```

But despite original example code works well, my modified test encounters `RuntimeError: Event loop is closed` when trying to set the second value.

Is there a way to parameterize asynchronous test fixtures?